# Getting wrong string from the toString() of the card

Tags: java, string, tostring

While I was trying to debug a very strange complication that happens when I try to get from the last round loser his highest ranking card and get it to my hand.

```
public Card highestRankingCard()
{
    Collections.sort(getHand());

    Card temp = hand.get(hand.size() - 1);

    return temp;
}
```

When printing to `JOptionPane` I am getting back a totally not relatable suit with what I get in hand.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You was the first place in last round and " + game.scores().lastRoundLoser().getName() + " was the last.\n Choose a card of rank 3 - 10 to swap with his highest ranking card.\n" + game.scores().lastRoundLoser().getName() + " has given you " + game.scores().lastRoundLoser().highestRankingCard().toString(), "Swap cards", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

The long code just gets the reference of the loser player, and calls the highestRankingCard() from him.
Basically what I do is call the toString of the card

```
public String toString()
{
    if(rank == 16)
        return "Black Joker";
    else if(rank == 17)
        return "Red Joker";
    else
    {
        String s = "";

        if(rank == 15)
        {
            s = s + "2";

            if(suit.equals("h"))
                s = s + " of hearts";
            else if(suit.equals("d"))
                s = s + " of diamonds";
            else if(suit.equals("c"))
                s = s + " of clubs";
            else if(suit.equals("s"))
                s = s + " of spades";

            return s;
        }
        else if(rank == 14)
        {
            s = s + "Ace";

            if(suit.equals("h"))
                s = s + " of hearts";
            else if(suit.equals("d"))
                s = s + " of diamonds";
            else if(suit.equals("c"))
                s = s + " of clubs";
            else if(suit.equals("s"))
                s = s + " of spades";

            return s;
        }

        if(suit.equals("h"))
            s = s + " of hearts";
        else if(suit.equals("d"))
            s = s + " of diamonds";
        else if(suit.equals("c"))
            s = s + " of clubs";
        else if(suit.equals("s"))
            s = s + " of spades";

        return s;
    }
}
```

The last added one is the card I get from the user: [image] 15 is the rank of deuce that's fine, but of diamonds? That is spades, but anyway I did another try and I get even a more joking sentence. The rank is missing! Is this even possible with the code above? Sorry if I am missing something. [image]

Note: Since Cards are drawn images if it was something with the file names I would have noticed. Just did a checkup and it is just fine

Comment: Use a debugger. Also, it seems your program is [stringly typed](http://wiki.c2.com/?StringlyTyped).

Comment: I'd check the Collections.sort implementation is correctly sorting the cards in the way that you were expecting - you might need to create your own comparable.

Comment: Tagging on Michael's comment, yes you need to not use hard-coded strings. Make an Enum class with your desired values instead, and pass those. It's by far best practice, and much easier to debug.

Comment: Also, you might want to extract all that duplicated code in a sort of lookup function.

Comment: It is not possible to tell what's possible or not with the code above as it is not the complete code. We have no idea which values fields of `Card` may or may not have. The problem could be just anything.

Comment: that rank is missing is obvious in the code above you never add it when the rank is not 14-17. For your other problems we are missing information.

Comment: That's A LOT of lines for a `toString` method.

Comment: Yep that's too bad for a `toString` I'll just go back to my previous simpler one. Thank you guys for the feedback, and sorry for asking such off topic question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is more than the rank not being printed. You need to ensure that your code is cohesive and minimise coupling. It looks like the toString method is doing a lot of work it really shouldn't be doing, everything in an object should be concerned only of the information contained within that object instance to the extent it's possible, and every method should be focused around doing one thing. Why don't you store the name and the colour of the card in the card so it's simply a case of doing

```
public String toString(){
    return this.colour + " " + this.name;
}
```

instead of trying to deduce which card instance you are. **You are the card.** You should be able to gather that information from yourself. Bottom line is good programming practices are good for a reason they help a lot of things, they help you with debugging, more methods = more stack traces to follow, much narrower range of possible problems, and they help with readability.

Sorry this probably isn't what you want to hear, but you might need to do some major refactoring before you can solve whats wrong.

Comment: Yea I realize now that what I was doing was hopeless, but after more than 6 hours into coding, sleepless, I couldn't just think of a simpler solution but was insisting in doing it via toString, and fyi got it edited to that bunch of code just lately, as it was as simple as you suggested. Thanks for your time

Comment: Ah, thee old sleepless coding. Now everything makes sense. Everything becomes a hell of a lot more difficult when you are tired, best to just sleep, chill and make sure you are using version control, that way you can roll back to a point where your code still made sense to you and work forward.